# SQL select maximum number of duplicates value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here I have this table:

**Copies**

```
nInv   |  Subject   |      LoanDate       | BookCode |MemberCode|
1      |Storia      |15/04/2019 00:00:00  |7844455544|  1       |  
2      |Geografia   |12/09/2020 00:00:00  |8004554785|  4       |  
4      |Francese    |17/05/2006 00:00:00  |8004894886|  3       |  
5      |Matematica  |17/06/2014 00:00:00  |8004575185|  3       |
```

I'm trying to find the value of the highest number of duplicates in the MemberCode column. So in this case I should get 3 as result, as its value appears two times in the table. Also, MemberCode is PK in another table, so ideally I should select all rows of the second table that match the MemberCode in both tables. For the second part I guess I should write something like `SELECT * FROM Table2, Copies WHERE Copies.MemberCode = Table2.MemberCode` but I'm missing out almost everything on the first part. Can you guys help me?

Comment: this is pretty basic, what did you try?

Comment: @MLeblanc It's actually not pretty basic, but is rather challenging.

Comment: You could use old-style join syntax - but you [shouldn't](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: And what should happen when there are no duplicates?

Comment: value of the highest number of duplicates - that means highest number, that has duplicates? Or most frequent number? Or highest count of number occurences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` and `limit`:

```
select membercode, count(*) as num
from t
group by membercode
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(counted) FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(MemberCode) AS counted 
FROM table_name GROUP BY MemberCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic functions, we can assign a rank to each member code based on its count.  Then, we can figure out what its count is.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.MemberCode, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t2.MemberCode) rnk
    FROM Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Copies c ON c.MemberCode = t2.MemberCode
    GROUP BY t2.MemberCode
)

SELECT cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
with top_dupe_member_cte as (
    select top(1) MemberCode, Count(*) 
    from MemberTable
    group by MemberCode
    order by 2 desc)
select /* columns from your other table */
from OtherTable ot
     join top_dupe_member_cte dmc on ot.MemberCode=dmc.MemberCode;
```